# Add two numbers together that are in the same cell in excel

Tags: excel, string, int

I have my schedule in excel and I want to find the hours. If I have the time slot in one cell how can I find their sum. So for example in B5 I have 10:30-7:00 and I want to find out how many hours that is, how can I do that?

Comment: Does 7:00 mean 7pm or 7am the next day? Or is it just 10:30 minus 7:00 i.e. 3hours 30 minutes? Or do you want to add them so the answer is 17:30? I think we need to see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to add and not subtract them, the basic formula is:-

```
=LEFT(B5,FIND("-",B5)-1)+RIGHT(B5,LEN(B5)-FIND("-",B5))
```

then format the result as time.

It will need adjustment if you want to subtract them and/or the result is negative or more than one day.